# mongodb aggregation pipeline the final results are getting duplicated

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using mongodb in Django with pymongo. Below is my pipeline:

```
plan_id = 1
search_string = ""
page = 1
limit = 25
pipeline = [
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "plans",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "$expr": {
                            "$and": [
                                {"$ne": ["$id", plan_id]},
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as": "plansList",
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "let": {"linkedPlansIds": "$linkedPlansIds"},
            "from": "plans",
            "localField": "linkedPlansIds",
            "foreignField": "id",
            "as": "LinkedPlans",
            "pipeline": [{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$planId", plan_id]}}}],
        }
    },
    {"$set": {"mergedArray": {"$setUnion": ["$LinkedPlans", "$plansList"]}}},
    {"$unwind": "$mergedArray"},
    {"$match": {"mergedArray.name": {"$regex": search_string, "$options": "i"}}},
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "mergedArray.isLinked": {"$in": ["$mergedArray.id", "$linkedPlansIds"]},
        }
    },
    {"$skip": (page - 1) * limit},
    {"$limit": limit},
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": None,
            "limit": {"$first": limit},
            "page": {"$first": page},
            "totalCount": {"$count": {}},
            "listData": {"$push": "$mergedArray"},
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "totalCount": 1,
            "page": 1,
            "limit": 1,
            "listData.id": 1,
            "listData.name": 1,
            "listData.isLinked": 1,
        }
    },
]


data = list(collection.aggregate(pipeline))
```

The results are below:

```
[
    {
        "limit": 25,
        "page": 1,
        "totalCount": 18,
        "listData": [
            {"id": 2, "name": "happ", "isLinked": True},
            {"id": 3, "name": "ddd", "isLinked": True},
            {"id": 4, "name": "sss", "isLinked": False},
            {"id": 5, "name": "eee", "isLinked": False},

            {"id": 2, "name": "happ", "isLinked": False},
            {"id": 3, "name": "ddd", "isLinked": False},
            {"id": 4, "name": "sss", "isLinked": False},
            {"id": 5, "name": "eee", "isLinked": False},

        ],
    }
]
```

So in the listData array you can see the results with same ID are occurring again. I'm working on this for hours and not getting a proper solution on this as I'm new to mongodb.
The results I'm trying to acheive here is that I have 'Plans" and "LinkedPlans" collection. If LinkedPlans is not there or empty then I need to fetch from "Plans" collection.

Comment: Hi, can you provide the sample input document to the question? Or reproduce it in the Mongo Playground. Thanks.